# Cross-platform means of getting user's home directory in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, cross-platform

Java has the convienient `System.getProperty("user.home")` to get the user's "home" directory in a platform-independent way.  What's the equivalent in Ruby?  I don't have a Windows box to play around with, and I feel like relying on tildes in filenames isn't the cleanest way.  Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The [`File.expand_path`](http://RubyDoc.Info/docs/ruby-core/1.9.2/File.expand_path) method uses the Unix convention of treating the tilde (`~`) specially, so that `~` refers to the current user's home directory and `~foo` refers to `foo`'s home directory.

I don't know if there's a better or more idiomatic way, but `File.expand_path('~')` should get you going.

Comment: is that true on Windows, tho?  The docs don't indicate as such

Comment: Everything on this page works (at least on Windows 7), but I think Dir.home and using tilde seem the best.

Answer (score 122):

With Ruby 1.9 and above you can use [`Dir.home`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-home).

Comment: Additionally, `Dir.home('my_username')` will give you the home directory of a specific user.

Answer (score 19):

This works on all operating systems

- For the current user

```
Dir.home
```

- For a given user

```
Dir.home('username')
```

**Note:** Username is case sensitive on Linux but not on Windows or macOS

Answer (score 11):

On unix platforms (linux, OS X, etc), `ENV["HOME"]`, `File.expandpath('~')` or `Dir.home` all rely on the `HOME` environment variable being set.  But sometimes you'll find that the environment variable isn't set--this is common if you're running from a startup script, or from some batch schedulers.  If you're in this situation, you can still get your correct home directory via the following:

```
require 'etc'
Etc.getpwuid.dir
```

Having said that, since this question is asking for a "cross-platform" method it must be noted that this won't work on Windows (`Etc.getpwuid` will return `nil` there.)  On Windows, `ENV["HOME"]` and the methods mentioned above that rely on it will work, despite the `HOME` variable not being commonly set on Windows--at startup, Ruby will fill in `ENV["HOME"]` based on the windows `HOMEPATH` and `HOMEDRIVE` environment variables.  If the windows `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` environment variables aren't set then this won't work.  I don't know how common that actually is in Windows environments, and I don't know of any alternative that works on Windows.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks for the pointer to the etc module.

Answer (score 10):

`ENV["HOME"]` or `ENV["HOMEPATH"]` should give you what you want.

```
homes = ["HOME", "HOMEPATH"]

realHome = homes.detect {|h| ENV[h] != nil}

if not realHome
   puts "Could not find home directory"
end
```

Comment: is that true on Windows, tho?

Comment: @davetron5000 That's what my code is doing, `HOMEPATH` is an environment variable only on Windows.

Comment: So, essentially we have to roll it ourselves, there's no system call to get it?  That is strangely lame for Ruby…

Comment: `HOMEPATH` on _Windows_ does not include the drive-letter - so won't work if user-folder resides in `D:`.