# Get user name in RubyMotion OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-mavericks, rubymotion, fileutils

I need to get the user's home directory or at least his name.

Using `FileUtils`, I need to move files based on their account name, and using `~/` doesn't seem to work.

How would I get the user's account name?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a rubymotion user yet, but in most rubies you can do

```
ENV["HOME"]
```

for the home directory and

```
ENV["USER"]
```

for the user to achieve exactly that using defined environment variables.

Comment: Thanks Patru, I have since found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020187/getting-home-directory-in-mac-os-x-using-c-language which suggests that may not be the best way. I'll give it (and the suggestions) a try and see :)

Comment: Of course you are right if you do not have control over what the rest of your process does with the environment. You could check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190930/cross-platform-means-of-getting-users-home-directory-in-ruby) for some more suggestions on getting the home directory using ruby, especially an explanation of `Etc.getpwuid.dir` (and why it does not work on Windows). It is surprising, that ruby which tries to follow the POLS does not provide a platform independent way to this seemingly simple task.

Answer (score 0):

To get to the document's path and create a new folder in OSX you could do.

```
directory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, true).first
directory = directory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Sub Folder")

fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager

fileExists = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(directory)
if (fileExists)
  NSLog("Folder already exists")
else
  if(!fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(directory, withIntermediateDirectories:true, attributes: nil, error: nil))
    NSLog("Failed to create folder")
  else
    NSLog("Successfully created folder")
  end
end
```

---

If all you want is the user account's name you can use [NSHost](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHost_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

---

For the home directory you could use NSHomeDirectory instead.

```
fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager
directory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSHomeDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, true).first
fm.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(directory, error: nil).each do |file|
  puts file # outputs each file under the home directory
  // Copy file here using NSFileManager
end
```

You can then use NSFileManager's [copyItemAtPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtPath%3atoPath%3aerror%3a)

---

Comment: Awesome thanks, I'll give it a go! What I'm trying to do is copy a file from a path that stems from with the users home directory, to some other directory. I also don't know the files name, so am using wildcard matches (*), which hasn't been working so far...